# PowerShell Argument Completer Performance / State Machine

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell argument completer (in C#) that does quite a bit of processing before it can return all completion results. I would like to offer IP address completion, but to do so I'm basically creating an IP address from four bytes, if it matches the `wordToComplete` I'll yield return a completion result with the value, and then I'll increment a byte and repeat the process. This has a potential to yield up to 65535 results, and it seems that PowerShell wants to gather all the results before it will actually use one. Does the argument completion in PowerShell do something to prevent a state machine from being... useful?

Has anyone dealt with this before? I tried to write my own state machine in case it was something to do with `yield return`, but no luck there either. Here's my current code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Language;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public sealed class IPv4AddressCompletionAttribute : ArgumentCompleterAttribute, IArgumentCompleter
    {
        public IPv4AddressCompletionAttribute()
            :base(typeof(IPv4AddressCompletionAttribute))
        {
        }
        public IEnumerable<CompletionResult> CompleteArgument(string commandName, string parameterName, string wordToComplete, CommandAst commandAst, IDictionary fakeBoundParameters)
        {
            wordToComplete += "*";
            string[]? octetStrings = wordToComplete?.Split('.');
            if (octetStrings?.Length > 4)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            IEnumerable<byte>[] ranges = new IEnumerable<byte>[4];
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                string? octetString = octetStrings?.Length > i ? octetStrings[i] : null;
                ranges[i] = CompleteOctet(octetString);
            }


            decimal returned = 0;
            foreach (byte firstOctet in ranges[0])
            {
                foreach (byte secondOctet in ranges[1])
                {
                    foreach (byte thirdOctet in ranges[2])
                    {
                        foreach (byte fourthOctet in ranges[3])
                        {
                            var ip = new IPAddress(new[] { firstOctet, secondOctet, thirdOctet, fourthOctet }).ToString();
                            yield return new CompletionResult(ip);
                            if (returned++ > MaximumReturnCount) yield break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<byte> CompleteOctet(string? initial)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(initial))
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(byte.MinValue, byte.MaxValue).Select(i => (byte)i);
            }
            else if (byte.TryParse(initial, out var byt))
            {
                return new[] { byt };
            }
            else
            {
                var wc = WildcardPattern.Get(initial, WildcardOptions.IgnoreCase);
                return Enumerable.Range(byte.MinValue, byte.MaxValue).Where(i => wc.IsMatch(i.ToString())).Select(i => (byte)i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is eliminate the `MaximumReturnCount` and associated features to allow the entire range to be returned. Instead of waiting for all (up to 255^4) possible options to be loaded into memory, I'd like to identify and return them one at a time as `TAB` is pressed. Is there any way to prevent PowerShell from loading every possibility, or other tricks anyone might have to help me in this situation?

Comment: Four loops of `byte.MaxValue` is 4,228,250,625 iterations. Are you sure that's not the problem?

Comment: @stuartd I have additional checks to narrow down the scope before starting, but that's exactly what the problem is. This is why I want a sort of state machine that only proceeds to find the next value when the user hits `tab`, instead of finding every value at once.

Comment: @Stroniax Think about what you're asking the computer to do.  You're using a completer which is designed to give you all of your options at once so that you can make a selection.  However, you want it to only give you one at a time.  That's not what the completer was designed to do.  This is very much a square peg with a round hole type of situation.

Comment: @Colyn1337 Indeed. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but that's what I meant by "Is there any way to work around this?" and "has anyone dealt with this before?" - I realize that what I'm doing is *particularly* insufficient for what I want, and wonder if anyone has ideas for alternatives that I could try or other ways to alleviate the issue I'm experiencing here.

Comment: Why are you auto-completing IP addresses? The point of these enums is generally to have a drop-down or tab-able list of all the valid choices for a user. Do you want to do IP address validation instead?

Comment: @user19702 IP address validation is as simple as setting the parameter type to `IPAddress`. What I want is to suggest a realistic value as opposed to ".\path" since that's never going to be helpful for an IP address parameter. Argument completion is less about *valid* results, and more about *realistic* results. For validity, I'd use an implementation of `ValidateArgumentsAttribute` or the `ValidateSetAttribute`.

Comment: Why calculate every IPv4 address? It seems like you could do the same thing by auto-completing `0.0.0.0`. Maybe something fancier like split the `initial` on `.`, check if between 0-255, and add `.0` octets as needed. `192.168[tab]` becomes `192.168.0.0`?